# Handling ¿ in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I have a program which gets data through web services and some of the data seems to be a format issue.

For example I get data like "XYZ ¿ ABC".

The issue is that the data length that I am expecting to receive is defined as say  VARCHAR2(9 BYTE).

In my Java program , I can see that the length of the data is 9 but somehow when trying to insert data on the Oracle side, I am getting a field length mismatch error (where Oracle is treating it as 10.

I changed my program to read the data in ANSI format as well but the problem is still there.

Please advise if there is some change I should make in my program to handle this (one of the idea is to use substring on Oracle side and limit the passed in data to 9 Bytes but I don't want to do this since I might lose some data in this case).

Regards.

Comment: `¿` normally indicates a character set conversion problem.  What is the correct string you are trying to handle?  What is the character set in your Oracle database?

Comment: The length of that data is 9 characters, but the number of bytes depends on the encoding. In UTF-8 it is 10 bytes. You should decide whether you want to change the definition of the field or sanitize the data prior to inserting.

Comment: `¿` is a place holder for a character which cannot be stored in your database or your client is not able to store. What is you database character set and what do you expect as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While "XYZ ¿ ABC" is 9 *characters*, it isn't 9 bytes.  This is because ¿ is a mutli-byte character in UTF-8.

Oracle has [two solutions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm#CACHCAHF) for enabling unicode in the database, but it would be too long to post the entire thing as an answer here.

Comment: No `¿` means any "not displayable" character. In many cases it will be a multi-byte character but it's not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that may be happening.   One is lossy compression.  In this case, you are saving a bad character in the database, and there's no way to "format" back because all these chars are incorrectly reduced to the same code.  In this case you can see the raw codes the data is saved as, with:

```
select DUMP( 'your string' ) from dual
```

The second case, is there's just a mismatch between the character sets.

For both issues, you need to make sure all the data you are passing around is encoded in the same charset.  UTF-8 is a commonly supported one.  ASCII is best if you don't have any non-US characters.

Things to check:

What charset is java using?
What charset is oracle saving the data as?
What charsets does your driver support?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by changing the datatype to 9 characters.